# Выводить ярлык категории wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Привет всем.
Не получается выводить короткие ссылки категории в шаблон category.php в цикле. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как выводить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$category = get_the_category();
echo $category[0]->slug;
```